# Mysql Stored Proc Passing String List

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I have this Stored Procedure below, **it works if my PostId is Integer** field
and i send postIdList as a comma separated string '1,2,3,4'...
**But if I change my PostId to GUID(char(36) it does not work for me.
it gives me an syntax error saying**

> "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '"2d9d3ebc-6c9f-467a-8181-8a38891756b)' at line 1"

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetComments`(
         IN  postIdList TEXT    
    )
BEGIN
set @sql = CONCAT('select * from PostComment where PostId in (', postIdList, ') ');
PREPARE q FROM @sql;
execute q;
END$$
```

this is how i am calling it
CAll GetComments(
'fff78ee0-396b-4300-952b-eee72d65261a,fff517dc-a7b7-441e-85bb-b5134828c0c9');

**Any Ideas how to resolve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ids are not integers.  You need to pass them in with single quotes or do something like this:

```
set @sql = CONCAT('select * from PostComment where PostId in (''',
                  replace(postIdList, ',', ''','''),
                  ''') ');
```

That is, replace each comma with a single quote, comma, single quote.  And then put quotes at the beginning and end of the list.